# Controlling the height of roof in tikz-qtree?

Tags: tikz-trees

I am trying to make the roof (triangle) shorter than the near branches. Is there any way to do that? Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=50]

\Tree [.S [.NP\1 [.Det the ] [.N cat ] ]
[.VP [.V sat ]
[.PP [.P \edge[roof]; {on} ]
[.NP [.Det the ] [.N mat ] ] ] ] ]

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Do you mean you want the node for "on" a bit shifted upwards and with the roof consequently shorter? How about what I wrote in my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=50]

\Tree [.S [.NP\1 [.Det the ] [.N cat ] ]
[.VP [.V sat ]
[.PP [.P \edge[roof]; \node[yshift=2em]{on}; ]
[.NP [.Det the ] [.N mat ] ] ] ] ];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: preview]

Comment: @mangotango if this answered your question you may consider marking it as accepted answer. Glad I could help!