# Adjust roof height and width in tikz-qtree

Tags: linguistics, tikz-qtree

I would like to adjust the height and width of certain roofs in my syntax trees.

I'm particularly interested in getting a roof with a long phrase/sentence to look better. In the image below, the "um cocar de índio" roof should not be so wide, but higher and less "flat", if I can explain myself clearly. Here's what it looks like right now:

[image]

I've looked at the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205253/controlling-the-height-of-roof-in-tikz-qtree), but it doesn't work for me because the "triangle" (roof) goes upside down, like in the image below (and the width of the roof still looks the same to me):

[image]

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tipa, tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}
\ex. \parbox{\textwidth}{\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=5pt, level distance=10pt]\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}} 
\Tree 
[ [ \edge[roof]; \node(v2) {[o rei]\textsubscript{F}} ; ]
[ [. \node(ct) {CT-$\lambda$\textsubscript{1}}; ]
[ [. \node(v1) {$t_1$} ; ]
[ [.me ]
[ [. deu ]
[ \edge[roof]; {um cocar de índio} ] ] ] ] ] ]
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (v1) to [bend left=45] (v2); 
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution. It requires the text of the roof node to be in an explicit `\node` with style `[roof node]`.  I've only shown the code for the downwards pointing roofs; for the other directions you can check the source code for `tikz-qtree`. I didn't change the width of the roof, which looks fine to me, but this could be done by adjusting the `x` coordinate in the coordinate addition.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tipa, tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\roofht}
\setlength{\roofht}{.5cm}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{linguex}
\tikzset{roof node/.style=
    {text height=\roofht+.5\baselineskip}}
\makeatletter
\def\roof@edge@down#1#2{(#1.south) -- ($(#2.north west)+(0pt,-\roofht)$) -- ($(#2.north east)+(0pt,-\roofht)$) -- cycle}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ex. \parbox{\textwidth}{\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=5pt, level distance=10pt]\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north},roof/.append={level distance=3em}} 
\Tree 
[ [ \edge[roof]; \node[roof node](v2) {[o rei]\textsubscript{F}} ; ]
[ [. \node(ct) {CT-$\lambda$\textsubscript{1}}; ]
[ [. \node(v1) {$t_1$} ; ]
[ [.me ]
[ [. deu ]
[ \edge[roof,]; \node[roof node]{um cocar de índio}; ] ] ] ] ] ]
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (v1) to [bend left=45] (v2); 
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: This worked great, thank you!